# I would like to have Cerberus tag

Tags: support, tags

Can someone please create [cerberus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cerberus) on Stack Overflow?

I would like to add it to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190286/can-i-create-unique-compound-constraints-on-eve-schema-definition) question, because the question is about [Python-Eve](http://python-eve.org/) schema definiton, which relies on [Cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/) for schema validation, as mentioned on the end of [this](http://python-eve.org/config.html#schema-definition) topic from Python-Eve documentation. Also there is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401982/python-eve-declare-an-array-of-object-ids-on-cerberus-schema) question on the same topic where the new tag would fit.

Comment: The significance of tags is overrated. Just make your question clear and try to make it self contained instead of posting many links or adding tags.

Comment: That said, I know too little of the technology to verify if the new tag would be warranted.

Comment: I'll make the tag If you can provide some actual reasoning. As of now, your question is basically "Can you create the Cerberus tag?".

Comment: Do either of the questions _require_ knowledge of Cerberus to answer? It looks like the second one you link did indeed require Cerberus knowledge to answer. If you don't think someone would have to know Cerberus to answer your first question (you don't even mention it in the question) then the tag isn't needed. It _may_ be useful in the case of the second question, but like Cerbrus, I know too little about the technology to verify that fact.

Comment: Well, the linked python-eve documentation mentions that it relies on Cerberus for validation of the schema definition, and since my question was about schema definition I thought that a specific tag for it could be useful. I don't know what kind of verification can I provide.

Comment: Added.  You'll have to write the tag wiki yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks @HansPassant.

Comment: Why someone creates a tag when neither the user have provided a really reasonable argument, nor meta agrees?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I legitimately thought this question was going to be about being able to find questions and answers written by you.

Comment: I agree with @gcw and disagree with πάνταῥεῖ, tags are not overrated, they are actually underestimated. Whenever possible, tags should be used to the maximum extent, tags are labels in structured format that improves a lot the search engines and indexing of questions, not to mention the subscribe feature that helps maintainers of open-source projects to provide attention and help to users through our community.

Comment: @Tarantula Tags are not meant for searches. Yes, they can help, but that's not what they are for. This is not twitter!

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone please create cerberus on Stack Overflow?

(Without googling what Cerberus is)

No. We shouldn't create this tag, and not because it isn't useful, but because is grossly misleading. Look, I know the three most annoying problems of programming: one by off errors and naming. This whatever is obviously affected by the latter. [This has happened before.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575)

(After googling)

Again, no. Cerberus is a python library and as I said before, it isn't immediately apparent what it is. Having a tag with just plain [cerberus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cerberus) in the long run (think about the children!) would bring about confusion. The most recommendable would be using [python-cerberus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-cerberus) like every other Python library out there. Consistency is what a programmer expect, and this is a site for programmers.

(on your two specific questions)

I fail to see how [eve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eve) doesn't accurately covers your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190286/can-i-create-unique-compound-constraints-on-eve-schema-definition). You seems to be asking how to bend Eve to your will, how is python-cerberus relevant? Because eve uses it for a functionality? Well, jQuery uses Javascript for some of it functionality, why we don't add [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to every [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) question? I'm sure that will earn you the ire of both camps.

Remember, tags are much more powerful than what people even think. They:

- [Help you find questions you can answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
- [Help you ignore questions you aren't interested in reading.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [Help you moderate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/213575) [the posts you care about.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/213575)
- [Help you ignore things you don't care about.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [Keeps you from wanting to stab people through the internet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

<sub>I maybe overused the PHP joke</sub>

These aren't willy nilly shinny things that serve no purpose but making us feeling good. They have a concrete purpose. Lets keep it like that.

Your second question may not even need the eve tag at all? It doesn't give me that vibes.

So, to summarize:

- Do not create a [cerberus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cerberus)
- Make sure you find a post where [python-cerberus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-cerberus) is meaningful on its own.
- The new tag doesn't increase your chances of getting an answer at all, since they have no followers.
- Once the tag has a sizable amount of answers, users may be awarded with the gold tag badge that increases their moderation powers, and possibly have other privileges too.